# Error when trying to assign a value to a foreign key

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a Ruby on Rails project and I get the following error when assigning a value to a foreign key:

```
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey in InformationController#import

Mysql2::Error: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key 
constraint fails (`sobrecupos_development`.`information`, CONSTRAINT 
`fk_rails_21c7b6e26c` FOREIGN KEY (`program_id`) REFERENCES `programs` 
(`id`)): UPDATE `information` SET `system_plan` = '2879.0', 
`program_id` = 2879, `updated_at` = '2018-04-03 15:32:07' WHERE 
`information`.`id` = 11
```

This key is supposed to be assigned from an external file but when I try to do so I get the error mentioned above. I tried to assign a key explicitly to check if it has to do with a possible nonexisiting value, but I still get this error.

Here is my schema.rb file

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20180402215605) do

  create_table "coordinators", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "lastname"
    t.integer  "department_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",                       null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                       null: false
    t.string   "email",               default: "", null: false
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",       default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "username"
    t.index ["department_id"], name: "index_coordinators_on_department_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_coordinators_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
    t.index ["username"], name: "index_coordinators_on_username", unique: true, using: :btree
  end

  create_table "departments", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
    t.string   "code"
    t.string   "abbreviation"
    t.index ["code"], name: "index_departments_on_code", unique: true, using: :btree
  end

  create_table "groups", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.integer  "subject_id"
    t.integer  "professor_id"
    t.integer  "available_spots"
    t.integer  "total_spots"
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
    t.index ["professor_id"], name: "index_groups_on_professor_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["subject_id"], name: "index_groups_on_subject_id", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "information", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.string   "level"
    t.integer  "program_id"
    t.string   "request_type"
    t.string   "act_resolution"
    t.date     "resolution_date"
    t.string   "dependency"
    t.decimal  "PAPA",                  precision: 10, scale: 1
    t.integer  "registered_credits"
    t.integer  "outstanding_credits"
    t.decimal  "completion_percentage", precision: 10
    t.integer  "tuition_amount"
    t.string   "academic_history_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",                                     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                                     null: false
    t.integer  "student_id"
    t.boolean  "was_saved"
    t.string   "system_plan"
    t.string   "academic_period"
    t.string   "document"
    t.index ["program_id"], name: "index_information_on_program_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["student_id"], name: "index_information_on_student_id", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "professors", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "programs", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "department_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
    t.string   "code"
    t.string   "program_type"
    t.index ["code"], name: "index_programs_on_code", unique: true, using: :btree
    t.index ["department_id"], name: "index_programs_on_department_id", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "students", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "lastname"
    t.string   "username"
    t.datetime "created_at",                       null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                       null: false
    t.string   "email",               default: "", null: false
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",       default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "document"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_students_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
    t.index ["username"], name: "index_students_on_username", unique: true, using: :btree
  end

  create_table "subject_requests", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.integer  "group_id"
    t.integer  "information_id"
    t.boolean  "was_canceled"
    t.string   "approbation_state"
    t.string   "inscription_state"
    t.string   "replace_to"
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
    t.boolean  "accept_other_group"
    t.string   "subject_code"
    t.string   "group_code"
    t.string   "typology"
    t.string   "subject_plan"
    t.index ["group_id"], name: "index_subject_requests_on_group_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["information_id"], name: "index_subject_requests_on_information_id", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "subjects", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "department_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
    t.string   "code"
    t.integer  "credits"
    t.index ["code"], name: "index_subjects_on_code", unique: true, using: :btree
    t.index ["department_id"], name: "index_subjects_on_department_id", using: :btree
  end

  add_foreign_key "coordinators", "departments"
  add_foreign_key "groups", "professors"
  add_foreign_key "groups", "subjects"
  add_foreign_key "information", "programs"
  add_foreign_key "information", "students"
  add_foreign_key "programs", "departments"
  add_foreign_key "subject_requests", "groups"
  add_foreign_key "subject_requests", "information", on_delete: :cascade
  add_foreign_key "subjects", "departments"
end
```

And here the line of code where I'm trying to assign a value to the foreign key

```
information.program_id = information.system_plan
```

Comment: Do you have a program with `id=2879` in your database?

Comment: Yes, that is the key assigned explicitly that I mentioned earlier, knowing beforehand that it exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there is 2 different approach you should try:

First, try cast to integer before assign:

```
 information.program_id = information.system_plan.to_i
```

Second, try assign object

```
information.program = Program.find(information.system_plan.to_i)
```

Besides these 2, I could not see other wrong doings in your code.